# How to check facebook custom audience standard events woking in facebook tag API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-tag

In my website, I am trying to track video viewers and I have installed Facebook pixel code and used following code below pixel code.

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
  content_name: AudienceId,   
  content_ids: [AudienceId],
  content_category: AudienceId,
  value: 1.50,
  currency: 'USD',
  referrer: document.referrer,
  userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
  language: navigator.language
});
```

I have created customer audience from Ads manager > Audiences > Create a custom audience > Website traffic.

After 5 days, In my website log and Google analytic, unique views were 241 but in Facebook , it is still showing "Audience too small" is there any specific limit after that It will come out from this message or is there something else?

How I can verify "custom Audience pixel has 9 standard events" installed and working properly in case of custom tag event?

Answer (score 0):

To check pixel fires correctly, you can download chrome extension " pixel helper". after that you just go to your website, and verify if the pixel events are firing or not.
you can also check back on ads manager under the pixel section, you will see which pixel events are being fired and the number of firing.